# ORA 12154 - for .NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle

I'm having problems with my connection to the ORACLE database.

When I try to open the connection, the following error occurs:

```
ora-12154 tns could not resolve service name
```

I have already checked tnsnames.ora, and it is correct, I also checked web.config if the directory I am looking for is also correct.

I did a test by changing my connection string by passing the TNSNames as hard coded information, and connected to the database.

I believe my application is not able to find or get to my TNSNames.

Comment: Which provider do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Verify following settings, they should all point to the same directory:

- TNS Environment variable `TNS_ADMIN`
- Registry entry `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle_Home_Name}\TNS_ADMIN`
- Registry entry `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_{Oracle_Home_Name}\TNS_ADMIN`
- Folder `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin` (consider symbolic link)
- .NET config file (`web.config`), section `configuration/oracle.manageddataaccess.client/version/settings/setting[@name="TNS_ADMIN"]` (See [Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver Configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/InstallManagedConfig.htm#ODPNT8162))